# How can I compute a fourier series with Wolfram alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

How can I compute the Fourier series of a function on a interval using Wolfram ? For example, the Fourier of $f(x)=x^2$ on $[0,2\pi]$ prolonged on $\mathbb R$ by $2\pi$ periodicity. For example, if I put **FourierSeries[x^2,x,n]**, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+series+x%5E2) will give me back the fourier series on $[-1,1]$. I saw in the manual of Wolfram, but it's not written how to modify the interval. Any idea ?

Comment: This question is not so much about mathematics as it is about using specific mathematical software. It *might* be on-topic at [Mathematica stack exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), but you would have to look up the rules there.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: If so, why is there a tag Wolfram Alpha ?

Comment: I am retracting my close vote; I am surprised to find that questions about mathematical software are on-topic here. My bad. However, the rules explicitly explicitly rule out Mathematica, and it is possible that WolframAlpha falls into that category.

Comment: @NewMath I was thinking something similar, but it looks like past questions with that tag (on topic) are usually asking about errors or results they have got from WA, and are querying their validity. So perhaps that could be a reason.